# Sluggish animations with CSS3 and jQuery for iOs

Tags: jquery, ios, css, jquery-animate

I'm about to create a webapp but when I've tried to animate some objects with jQuery or CSS3, they are sluggish, unfluid, like I have on my computer (or the iOs Simulator).

I think this is it because the iPhone is not enough powerful to animate objects (because when I've tried my animation on the iOs Simulator, they are all right.) But how **JQTouch** or **jQuery Mobile**  get fluid animations on iOs ?

I'll check your answer and at the same time, checking the **JQTouch** and **jQuery Mobile**'s sourcecode.

Thanks for helping !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a look at GSAP jquery plugin: [GSAP](http://www.greensock.com/jquery-gsap-plugin/)

> Up to 20x faster than jQuery’s native animate() method. See the
>   interactive [speed comparison](http://www.greensock.com/js/speed.html) for yourself. Works exactly the same as
>   the regular jQuery.animate() method. Same syntax. No need to change
>   your code. Just load the plugin (and TweenMax or TweenLite &
>   CSSPlugin) and you’re done.

Comment: Gonna look at that, even if this is not for comercial pruposes. Thanks anyway ! :D

Comment: Sure can be use for commercial purpose, ask them for license.